# Hide "out of stock" label on woocommerce archive page

Tags: woocommerce

This is my first question on this nice place.

So correct me if i'm doing something wrong.

My question:
How do I hide the "out of stock" (Dutch: "niet op voorraad") label on the woocommerce archive page?

The label is showing up in the top of the thumbnail.

I'm using the avada theme

I hope someone could help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can tell you can hide it with CSS. But we need code to give a more complete answer. Read the "How to ask" section.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response!
This is my website: http://www.test.nickreijrink.nl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a div over the image that say Out of stock, so just find the class of the div and set it to display none in the css

try to add this in the css file

```
.fusion-out-of-stock {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: okey, updated my answer